# How to write BigTable table data into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am trying to read a *GCP BigTable - table* to a *pandas dataframe*, and currently, the function I am using to fetch rows from BigTable is `read_rows()`, which returns **PartialRowData**.

##### Code:

```
from google.cloud import bigtable

client = bigtable.Client(admin=True)
instance = client.instance(bigTable_parms['instance_id'])
table = instance.table('s2')

row_data = table.read_rows()  # table.yield_rows()
for i in row_data:
    print(type(i))
```

##### Output:

> <class 'google.cloud.bigtable.row_data.PartialRowData'>

##### Query:

How do we read the values from `PartialRowData` obj?

Comment: Can you please try checking print_row? You can check the [following snippet.](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigtable/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/reads/read_snippets.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example on how to call `read_rows` in this documentation:
https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/table.html#google.cloud.bigtable.table.Table.read_rows

```
for row in table.read_rows():
    # replace with your own COLUMN_FAMILY_ID and COLUMN_NAME
    cell = row.cells[COLUMN_FAMILY_ID][COLUMN_NAME][0] 
    print(cell.value.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I am currently iterating over `table.scan()` @Mariatta, thanks for your suggestion. I will not use which ever method takes less time to get table data.